# Why can I select deleted rows use cql with thrift client API on cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

The Cassandra version is 1.1.1 and thrift client version is 1.0. First I insert four row into Cassandra with cql (call method `Cassandra.client.execute_cql_query()`). Then I delete one with cql and then I query date with Cassandra Cluster Admin (PHP client) that the row have been deleted.

But when I queried date with cql `SELECT * FROM mycolumnfamily` the row still exists! Can anybody tell why that happened?

Answer (score 2):

See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#range_ghosts and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3982